# ELK stack on AWS and web app on Digital Ocean, how and can I grab logs from the later?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elk

I have a python website hosted on digital ocean and ELK stack - Elastic Search, Kibana, Logstash - on AWS. I'm trying to understand how to feed the logs files from my python web app on digital ocean to the ELK stack on AWS:

- Is it possible to feed them via the internet between different servers?
- Do you I have to install nginx to be able to see kibana reports?
- Do I have to install ssl certificates for my AWS stack?

Comment: How did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Yes.
- No.
- No.

Methinks you might have wanted to ask a more open-ended question.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a simple reverse proxy in aws with https and basic auth that proxies to elasticsearch, then on your machine with the python app in DO install rsyslog-elasticsearch (if using ubuntu/debian) and configure it to forward logs with the un/pw and url of the es proxy.